# Loop Relative Reference

Tags: excel, vba, loops, reference

I am trying to loop a relative reference.
I have a date referenced in CG9 to the first cell of a column of dates.
Then it does some operations, and I would like CG9 to change its reference to the date in the second row.

Between each change of loop I'm doing some operations.

```
Sub Macro7()

Dim i As Long

For i = -2 To 3451

    Range("CG9").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-i]C[-24]"
    '#operations

Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro7()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = -2 To 3451
        Range("CG9").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-" & i & "]C[-24]"
    Next i
End Sub
```